# Upgrading Azure SDK and Azure Storage version to latest

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I am a beginner in Azure. I had a soln which was using the old version of SDK 2.1 and now have upgraded to 2.6 on my local. I use Visual Studio Team Services to deploy it on the cloud(which has the old version). All is working fine. So I have deployed to cloud using Team Services. But the cloud service still shows the old version. Is there any way I can check anything to see of the upgraded version 2.6 has been transitioned to the cloud service ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `cloud service still shows the old version`?

Comment: when I log onto the http://manage.windowsazure.com and navigate to my cloud service the dashboard shows the version as old version of SDK. It should refresh to a new version after I have successfully deployed to the cloud with all the recent version dlls from my local.Please Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Have you upgraded your Azure project or just installed the 2.6 sdk on your machine? In Visual Studio right-click -> properties on your Azure project - does it say Microsoft Azure Tools version 2.6?

Comment: Hi alex, Thanks for your reply. But I am not able to find the Azure version info when I click on the project. I have several projects under one solution. Do you mean to say in the References folder where there are several dlls ? Also, I have downloaded the Azure SDK 2.6 on my machine. How can I upgrade my project dlls on the basis of that ? Please reply.

Comment: Hi, sorry only just seen your reply (BTW if you reply with @name in your comment the user will receive a notification in their inbox). I have added my reply as an answer so that I could include a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have installed the latest sdk on your machine you will still have to upgrade your project within Visual Studio.
To do this: Within your solution select the Azure Cloud Service project (the one that contains the ServiceDefinition.csdef etc). Press Alt+Enter *or* right-click and from the context menu select properties (found at the very bottom).
This will open the document page shown below and will display the version of the Azure sdk your project is using. If a newer version is found on your machine you will see an upgrade button.

[image: screenshot of azure project properties page]